# Adding a new dropdown menu box with a click of a link

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Below is a javascript function that adds a new dropdown menu box. It works but when i put a `name` in select name and `value` in option value, it will not work.

```
function add() {
  var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
  var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
  numi.value = num;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
  newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<select> <option> Apple </option> <option> Orange </option> </select>";  
}
```

What could the problem be? Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: `<a  href="#" onclick="add();">Add another?</a>` and a `<div id="myDiv">` to specify where to place the added drop down menu.

Comment: Where is element which id = 'theValue'?

Comment: I have `<input type="hidden" value="0" id="theValue" />` before the `a href`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place/append the element to the body too. Here's what you need to add in your function:

```
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

Check the [output/usage](http://jsfiddle.net/dWp3b/embedded/result/).

Comment: Thank you! So I did some minor modifications in your suggestion. I just did this: `if($ctr<5){ ni.appendChild(newdiv); $ctr++; }` to limit the number of clicks. But whenever I add the `name` in select name and `value` in option value, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes inside your innerHTML string if you define that string with double quotes:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<select name=\"name\"> <option value=\"value\"> Apple </option> <option> Orange </option> </select>";
```

Alternatively, use single quotes to define the string, or the HTML attribute values (although the standard is double quotes for HTML attributes)

Comment: Thank you! So I can still access those values if I need to?